# Mist stuck not downloading last 100 blocks

Tags: solidity, mist

My mist wallet won't download the final blocks it needs to be fully synced to the blockchain. I have 0.18 ether in my account which is visible on etherscan, but it won't show on Mist.

Is getting stuck on the final few blocks a known issue?  How do I get the final blocks and see my balance in mist?

Comment: Everybody seems to be complaining about the same problem - walkarounds offered (leave mist and download the blockchain using a different node such as Parity) - but no-one seems to know WHY the problem occurs. In my case stuck at last 200 blocks.... Stepping over to an online exchange is also not an option (most of them are only middle men anyway) - why would you trust them? So my advice is to abandon Ethereum and look elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had these problems when trying to sync with Mist. All the balances of my accounts were always showing as 0, and often Mist would stay at a few hundred blocks behind, and never fully sync.

For me, the problem went away when I updated Mist to version 0.9.1, clicked the **Develop** menu and enabled **Sync with Light client (beta)**

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems and moved to Parity. Syncing is much faster (as in, node is functional I’m around half an hour, vs day+ for mist/geth) and I never had problems syncing the entire chain. Interface also much easier to use, web based.  I have both Mist & Parity, but I prefer parity. (Then again, I don’t use their multi-sigs...)